# How can I set up IP whitelisting on an IP camera without support for whitelists?

Tags: smart-home, security, privacy, digital-cameras, whitelisting

The camera in question is a [Ring Stick Up Cam](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C6DXMX0). I want to add an additional layer of security and prevent anyone from peeking (listening) into my home.

I thought that it might be good if I could set up some kind of IP whitelist, so only requests from authorized sources would get through towards the camera.

I have a ZTE Speedport Entry 2i router + modem by my Internet provider ([Hungarian manual](http://www.telekom.hu/static-la/sw/file/speedport_entry_2i_hasznalati_utmutato.pdf) just for the picture) ([English manual](https://www.cosmote.gr/fixed/documents/10280/87751345/Speedport_Entry_2i_Maintenance_Management_EN_v_2_1.pdf/e5aa9ed9-8e66-4d3b-8283-b79d67e0ded9) it seems to be the same device).

Is this a reasonable idea and if so how could someone set up such service for an IP camera?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have to start out by saying, this will have to take place on the router.  I looked into the camera, but it simply seems to be too manufacturer set to be able to run a crack that complex on.  Perhaps if you did some firmware replacement you could manage, but not simply.

With your particular router, it appears that you can.  I don't actually have your router, so I could be reading the documentation wrong, but it appears that you should be able to.  IF I'm reading right, follow these steps: (adapted from [cosmote documentation](https://www.cosmote.gr/fixed/documents/10280/87751345/Speedport_Entry_2i_Maintenance_Management_EN_v_2_1.pdf/e5aa9ed9-8e66-4d3b-8283-b79d67e0ded9))

1. Go under `Internet > Security > Filter Criteria.`
2. Select the radio button `on` beside `URL filter.`
3. Select `New Item.`
4. Type in any name and the IP of your camera and Apply.
5. Click `IP filter - IPV4` to open the IPV4 filters page.
6. Edit the settings under Destination IP and  Source IP range to match your requirements.

I could be wrong, but that appears to be the method.  :)  You might have to apply multiple rules to rule out all but the IP's you want: I'm not sure.

If you are unable to block all traffic except the IP you want on your router, the answer is, **no, it is not possible, short of buying a new router.**

Hope it works!